# Different ways to dynamically create pointers to objects in C++

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I learned some basic C in school, and continued using C for a while.

If I wanted to create something on the heap, I used `malloc()` and `free()` for it.

After some time passed, I started using some C++ and work with objects. I was told that I should not use `malloc()` and `free()` in C++, but rather `new` and `delete`, which made sense to me because I now could use custom constructors for my objects when creating them on the heap.

Now I read that you should try to avoid raw pointers as much as possible, and rather try to use smart pointers. In my case, I only need the object at one place, but declare it at the start of my program and do not have to copy it somewhere, so I guess I should use `std::unique_ptr`?

```
A* a1 = nullptr;
a1 = (A*)malloc(sizeof(A));     // cant call constructor
// Do stuff
free(a1);

A* a2 = nullptr;
a2 = new A(2);
// Do stuff
delete a2;

std::unique_ptr<A> a3 = nullptr;
a3 = std::unique_ptr<A>(new A(3));
// Do stuff
// No need to delete

std::unique_ptr<A> a4 = nullptr;
a4 = std::make_unique<A>(4);
// Do stuff
// No need to delete
```

I came up with these methods to create a pointer to my object.

- `a1` is useless for me because I can not call a constructor
- `a2` is apparently bad because I have to manually manage the memory?

So I thought I should use either `a3` or `a4`, but I am still left with some questions.

Did I get it right that I do not need to delete anything with either of those two variants, and that the class destructor will be called when the `std::unique_ptr` goes out of scope? Are there other options? And which would be the best choice?

Comment: The best choice depends entirely on what exactly you are doing, but `a4` will be the default in most cases

Comment: `Are there other options?` Is a very broad question. There are infinite other options.

Comment: _"I only need the object at one place"_  Then you very likely don't need a pointer at all.  Create an `A` instead of an `A*` or `unique_ptr<A>`.  It's both faster and simpler.

Comment: @DrewDormann I actually have an array of the A* in a class as a member and want to set it from the outside of the other class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `a1` is useless for me because I can not call a constructor

You can, using [placement-new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) if I am not mistaken:

```
new (a1) A();
```

> Did I get it right that I do not need to delete anything with either of those two variants, and that the class destructor will be called when the `std::unique_ptr` goes out of scope?

Yes.

> And which would be the best choice?

You would just use:

```
auto a4 = std::make_unique<A>(4);
```